# How do you access scrollViewDidScroll from a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller with a UIScrollView embedded as a sub view.  I embed it as follows:

CaptionViewController : UIViewController

Inside ViewDidLoad

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
scrollView.contentMode = (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit);
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3200, 320);
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Next I'm trying to wire up the scrollViewDidScroll event so I can execute some code each time the user swipes the scroll view.  However, I can figure out how to access this event.  I think the answer lies in delegation somehow.  I tried importing UIScrollView.h and setting the scrollView delegate to the CaptionViewController as follows:

```
[scrollView setDelegate:self]
```

Still I cannot access scrollViewDidScroll.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to setting the delegate of the scroll view, you have to implement the delegate method in your `CaptionViewController.m`.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // handle scroll event
}
```

Also make sure your `CaptionViewController` conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol. In the .m file:

```
@interface CaptionViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end
```

There is no need to import `UIScrollView.h`. You get this already.

Comment: Thank you.  I was not implementing <UIScrollViewDelegate> in my interface.  That solved it!